# Using find bar routines programmatically causes find bar to appear

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

**Update**: It appears that the fix for [bug 967982](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=967982) is what's causing this. It would still be great to know either (a) how to work around this or (b) if there's an alternative way to find text in a given page.

One of my Firefox extensions programmatically uses the browser's find bar to locate text on a web page. In recent versions of Firefox, executing my add-ons code causes the find bar to appear when a search term is *not* found, something it didn't do previously. My routine looks like this:

```
// Reuse the find bar mechanisms in Firefox (we get a bunch of stuff for free that way)
FindInPage: function(term, e) {
    var findBar = document.defaultView.gFindBar;
    var shiftKey = e.shiftKey;
    var findObj;
    var cachedFindTerm;

    if ("_find" in findBar) {
        findObj = {
            find: function(t) {
                findBar._find(findBar._findField.value = t);
            },
            findNext: function() {
                 findBar._findAgain(false);
            },
            findPrevious: function() {
                 findBar._findAgain(true);
            }
        };

        cachedFindTerm = gFindBar._findField.value;
    } else {
        findObj = findBar;
        cachedFindTerm = getBrowser().findString;
    }

    if (cachedFindTerm == term) {
        if(shiftKey)
            findObj.findPrevious();
        else
            findObj.findNext();
    } else {
        findObj.find(term);
        if(shiftKey)
            findObj.findPrevious();
    }
},
```

Is there some way I can prevent the find bar from appearing when this block gets executed? I'm aware that using private functions like this is not a best practice, but is there a better way to find a given word in a web page? Some sort of search API available to add-on authors that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You can use the FindBar.jsm features without it opening but you have to actually use those internal functions I think. I didn't read totally your question but I made this addon which uses the findbar feature - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hiliteonselection/